# How to add attributes to existing items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The /give and /replaceitem commands are fine if I want to create a new item with a custom attribute, but is there a command to add an attribute to an existing item?

The closest I've gotten to this is adding attributes to an entity representing a dropped item, but the attributes do not carry over to the item once picked up:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,r=1] {AttributeModifiers:[{...}]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! What you're doing works just fine, with some minor tweaks.

To apply the attribute modifier to the item, you need to do this instead:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,r=1] {Item:{tag:{AttributeModifiers:[{<attribute stuffs>}]}}}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?  Because I don't think it'll work.

Comment: @MBraedley I have tested this. I can put up a gif, if you want.

Comment: That was me telling you that your command is wrong.  You're missing a pair of braces.

Comment: Oh, heh, I copied it over wrong. Whoops. Thanks, @MBraedley. ;P

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.  Still getting the hang of this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated command syntax for 1.13+:

`/data merge entity @e[type=item,distance=..5,limit=1] {Item:{tag:{AttributeModifiers:[{<attribute stuff>}]}}}`